# I can't see the errors on MAMP PRO

Tags: php, mamp-pro

I changed the three of php.ini files on my MAMP but it is still not showing the errors??

Does anyone know what to do in this? How can I show errors in MAMP PRO?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run phpinfo(); and make sure the ini file it lists is the one you're editing.

Comment: thank you! I just solved it, it has to run on another file with error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: @LiridonaArifi All questions on SO deserve resolution.  Either deletion, closure, or accepted answer.  Please be a good SO citizen and provide some form of resolution to your question.